# Concatenate two audio blobs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api, recorder

I am using [recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) to record two audio files on my web page, which then creates recordings as blobs.

Once I have these audio blobs I would like to concatenate them into one track.

How can I do it?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/audioconcat   is node package used for audio concat

Comment: @RobertRowntree I need pure JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

if you save the raw PCM of the orig clips from the callbacks on the buffer of the mic, i think you can just provide array of bufferd Clips to a new blob constructor.

```
 let recordedBlob = new Blob($ArrBuff[clip1,clip2], { type: "audio/*" });
    recording.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
```

Comment: It is important the order? I have a big file (13 chunks) and a socket, and the order could be incorrect

Answer (score -1):

if you have them in audio files such as wav or mp3 etc., you can use Audacity to edit them and export however you want.  or use ffmpeg to concat them together.  I would use Audacity because it makes it easier to edit the material.